# Is it right to have a setter to set different type than the property type?

Tags: c#

e.g.

```
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string DataTypeString
    {
        get 
        {
            return _dataType.ToString();
        }
        set 
        { 
            _dataType = Type.GetType(value); 
        }
    }

    private Type _dataType;

    public Type DataType
    {
        get { return _dataType; }
        set { _dataType = value; }
    }
```

In the above code, first property type is string, however the setter sets, the _dataType which is of System.Type

Comment: Isn't this the whole point of properties - they provide a level of abstraction from the underlying fields.

Comment: Seems weird to me to have two getters/setters for one property though

Answer (score 3):

You can and often benificial to do so for get properties.

Type conversion in set properties likley be more contraversial. Properties are normally expected to be lightweight, not to throw exceptions and normally `x.YYY=newValue;` expected to result in `x.YYY==newValue` to be true - these may be hard to achieve if type conversion happens.

I.e. in your particular example allowing to set type by string as property feels like a bad idea - what is expected behavior of `x.DataTypeString="42";`? You may want to consider some other way to enable XML serialization of your property...

Comment: That's completely correct. But that's why using a property could be a good thing. He may validate that the string corresponds to a valid type inside the property so that he doesn't have to do it outside of it everytime he needs to assign it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. That's the purpose of the properties. The user of the property doesn't need to know what's behind it. He/she just sets or gets a string and that's all they need to know.

Comment: Well, this could lead to a null value being assigned to the field if the type isn't found. That could lead to a tricky bug.

Comment: @Kirk, that could easily be fixed by throwing an exception.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen we don't really want to be throwing exceptions in properties

Comment: @James, it's not perfect, but it should be okay as long as it really is very exceptional.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its ok, but I would prefer to just do this, which less odd and less verbose:

```
    public void SetDataType(string value) {
        _dataType = Type.GetType(value); 
    }

    public void SetDataType(Type value) {
        _dataType = value; 
    }

    public Type DataType { get; private set; }
```

As was already mentioned, it seems rather odd to have two getter/setter pairs for the same private variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing the purpose of this class. But in general, I think I'd be confused by having two properties with the same backing field (so that changing one affects the other).

There are exceptions though. For example, in a Circle class, I would find it perfectly reasonable to have both a Radius property and a Diameter property. So again, it kind of depends on the purpose of your class.

Also, in the example you provided, it doesn't seem like the `DataTypeString` property provides much benefit. If you remove it, callers could achieve the same effect by simply calling

```
foo.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
```

or

```
string dataTypeString = foo.DataType.ToString()
```

.